# How to resolve InvalidClientError (oauthlib.oauth2)

Tags: python, flask, google-signin, flask-oauthlib

I am currently trying to integrate a Google Sign-In feature into my local Flask Web Application with OAuthlib. While trying to run the finished implementation of the Flask Google-Login feature as shown [here at RealPython](https://realpython.com/flask-google-login/), I ran into this error:

> oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidClientError: (invalid_client) Unauthorized

which points to this line of code in my `routes.py` file:

```py
client.parse_request_body_response(json.dumps(token_response.json()))
```

I have no clue as to why I'm getting this error, how do I resolve this?

Here are samples from both my `app/__init__.py` file and `routes.py` file:

**`app/__init__.py`**

```py
import os
from flask import Flask
from config import Development
from flask_caching import Cache
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationClient

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Development)

cache = Cache(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")
client = WebApplicationClient(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)

from app import routes, forms, login, models
```

---

**`app/routes.py`**

```py
import os

...

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET")
GOOGLE_DISCOVERY_URL = (
    "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"
)

def get_google_provider_cfg():
    return requests.get(GOOGLE_DISCOVERY_URL).json()

...


@app.route("/login-google")
def login_google():
    google_provider_cfg = get_google_provider_cfg()
    authorization_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["authorization_endpoint"]

    request_uri = client.prepare_request_uri(
        authorization_endpoint,
        redirect_uri=flask.request.base_url + '/callback',
        scope=["openid", "email", "profile"],
    )
    return flask.redirect(request_uri)

@app.route("/login-google/callback")
def callback():
    code = flask.request.args.get("code")
    google_provider_cfg = get_google_provider_cfg()
    token_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["token_endpoint"]
    token_url, headers, body = client.prepare_token_request(
        token_endpoint, authorization_response=flask.request.url,
        redirect_url=flask.request.base_url, code=code
    )
    token_response = requests.post(
        token_url, headers=headers,
        data=body, auth=(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET),
    )
    client.parse_request_body_response(json.dumps(token_response.json())) ##  <--- Error Occurs Here!
    userinfo_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["userinfo_endpoint"]
    uri, headers, body = client.add_token(userinfo_endpoint)
    userinfo_response = requests.get(uri, headers=headers, data=body)
    flags = userinfo_response.json().get("email_verified")

    
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want to make google - login to your flask website?
I have my own code, it work well
First, **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
import dir
from flask_mail import Mail

# init SQLAlchemy so we can use it later in our models
db = SQLAlchemy()
mail = Mail()


GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxx"
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = False
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret-key-goes-here'

    # app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////' + str(dir.dir) + '/admin.sqlite' #this is dabase, you can change it.
    app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
    app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'youremail@gmail.com'
    app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'yourpass'
    app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
    app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
    app.config['OAUTH_CREDENTIALS']  = {
        'google': {
            'id': GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID,
            'secret': GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET
        }
    }
    mail.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    from .models import User
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))



    # blueprint for auth routes in our app
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    from .serv import serv as serv_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(serv_blueprint)

    # blueprint for non-auth parts of app
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    from .search import search as sear_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(sear_blueprint)

    from .dash import dash as dash_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(dash_blueprint)

    from .dlf import dlf as dlf_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(dlf_blueprint)

    from .contact import contact as contact_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(contact_blueprint)


    return app
```

Second, in main.py, you can change to app.py, for easy code in future, i think you should user [Blueprint](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, redirect, flash, url_for, current_app
from flask_login import login_required, current_user, login_user
from project.function import cmsHaravan as hara, cmsCalendar as cal
from .function import config as cf, cmsContacts as ct
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from .models import User, Orders, Shop, Services
from . import db, mail
from flask_mail import Message
import random
import string
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
import json
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from urllib.request import urlopen
import dateutil
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
class OAuthSignIn(object):
    providers = None

    def __init__(self, provider_name):
        self.provider_name = provider_name
        credentials = current_app.config['OAUTH_CREDENTIALS'][provider_name]
        self.consumer_id = credentials['id']
        self.consumer_secret = credentials['secret']

    def authorize(self):
        pass

    def callback(self):
        pass

    def get_callback_url(self):
        return url_for('main.oauth_callback', provider=self.provider_name,
                       _external=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_provider(self, provider_name):
        if self.providers is None:
            self.providers = {}
            for provider_class in self.__subclasses__():
                provider = provider_class()
                self.providers[provider.provider_name] = provider
        return self.providers[provider_name]


class GoogleSignIn(OAuthSignIn):
    openid_url = "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"

    def __init__(self):
        super(GoogleSignIn, self).__init__("google")
        self.openid_config = json.load(urlopen(self.openid_url))
        self.session = OAuth2Session(
            client_id=self.consumer_id,
            redirect_uri=self.get_callback_url(),
            scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email '
        )

    def authorize(self):
        auth_url, _ = self.session.authorization_url(
            self.openid_config["authorization_endpoint"])
        return redirect(auth_url)

    def callback(self):
        if "code" not in request.args:
            return None, None

        self.session.fetch_token(
            token_url=self.openid_config["token_endpoint"],
            code=request.args["code"],
            client_secret=self.consumer_secret,
        )

        me = self.session.get(self.openid_config["userinfo_endpoint"]).json()
        print(me)
        return me["family_name"], me["given_name"], me["email"], me["picture"]


@main.route('/authorize/<provider>')
def oauth_authorize(provider):
    # Flask-Login function
    if not current_user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider)
    return oauth.authorize()


@main.route('/callback/<provider>')
def oauth_callback(provider):
    if not current_user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider)
    flamily_name, given_name, email, avatar = oauth.callback()
    print("Successfull to get email", email)
    if email is None:
        # I need a valid email address for my user identification
        flash('Invalid')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    # Look if the user already exists
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if not user:
        # Create the user. Try and use their name returned by Google,
        # but if it is not set, split the email address at the @.
        name = given_name
        if name is None or name == "":
            name = email.split('@')[0]

        # We can do more work here to ensure a unique nickname, if you
        # require that.
        user = User(firstname=given_name, lastname=name, email=email, avatar=avatar)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
    # Log in the user, by default remembering them for their next visit
    # unless they log out.
    user.firstname = flamily_name
    user.lastname = given_name
    user.avatar = avatar
    db.session.commit()
    login_user(user, remember=True)
    return redirect(url_for('main.profile'))
```

Third, in html

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col "><span class="label-input-group"><br></span>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('main.oauth_authorize', provider='google') }}" class="btn btn-light btn-lg btn-block border-primary text-primary">
                        Login with google with out password
                    </a>
                </div>


            </div>
```

For my code, you have to make the model in models.py

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import db
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)  # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(30))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(30))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(10))
    password = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

To use model, i use the [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you! I've remodled some of my code to reflect yours, and it seems the issue was that the requests were occuring over HTTP not HTTPS (though why I didn't get that error is beyond me) and this helped! =D

Comment: Google support localhost without https, you can try it